# Microsoft Remote Desktop - multiple monitors, switch primary / main monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I'm using Microsoft Remote Desktop version 1.2.3577.0 (x64), and Windows 10 on both local and remote.

[image]

I have three monitors connected to my local machine and I'm using two of them for a remote session.

[image]

I'd like to swap which of the two monitors is the primary monitor on the remote session - how do I do that?  I'd like the left side to be the primary.

[image]

If I go into Display settings on the remote session I get a message saying "the display settings can't be changed from a remote session":

[image: Display Settings]

Comment: I'm guessing you are going to have to swap 2 & 3, so 2 is on the left. I've had similar struggles in the past where you end up just having to swap the physical wiring or displays to persuade it to match what you want.

Comment: Note : Microsoft Remote Desktop has less features than Remote Desktop Connection.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, you will need to manually edit rdp file associated with the remote desktop connection.
It will have a line similar to **selectedmonitors:s:2,1**, this setting maps local monitors to remote ones.
The first number determines the local monitor that will take the role of the remote main.

How to open and configure rdp file to set up multi monitor remote desktop, as well as how to obtain correct "number" for a given local monitor is described on many blogs, see for example Method 3 in
https://www.helpwire.app/blog/remote-desktop-dual-monitor/
There are additional examples in
https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-remote-desktop-in-full-screen-on-2-out-of-3-monitors
and
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/665.how-to-set-the-monitor-for-a-remote-desktop-session-in-a-multi-monitor-setup.aspx

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1173204)

Comment: I believe this answer may apply when using Remote Desktop Connection.  But with the **Microsoft Remote Desktop** application I'm not aware that there is an RDP file that can be edited.